# How to get and preview the http image url from DB in under the HTML file type

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I did achieve the preview image function use js and then I tried to get the http image url from DB, but it doesn't geted and showed that particular image in image tag

I did try the got dynamic images to preview under the HTML tag element, but the dynamic images get in the DB, but it doesn't show in the preview area, So How do achieve this in this film?

Note that:::
In the geted image url prefix has http, that set attribute only allowed for https

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are unable to retrieve the image URL from your DB? How are you doing that? Are you sure your DB queries are correct and that the image URL exists in the DB? Or are you able to take the image URL from the database, but can't use it as a source for your `img` elements? Can you show us some code, so that we can offer useful suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I mock the preview function in my side, since I test in a cshtml file, so I surround the js code with `@section Scripts{}`.

```
<div>
    <button id="btn1">preview pic 1</button>
    <button id="btn2">preview pic 2</button>
</div>
<p>
    <img id="ImgPreview" />
</p>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#ImgPreview").attr('src', "");
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:7041/api/hello/getImgUrl?index=1",
                type:"get",
                success:function(data){
                    console.info(data);
                    $("#ImgPreview").attr('src', data);
                }
            })
        })

        $("#btn2").click(function () {
            $("#ImgPreview").attr('src', "");
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:7041/api/hello/getImgUrl?index=2",
                type: "get",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.info(data);
                    $("#ImgPreview").attr('src', data);
                }
            })
        })

    </script>
}
```

[image]

In my Controller, I just return the image url so that it can be used in `<img>` tag.

```
[HttpGet("getImgUrl")]
        public string getImgUrl(string index) {
            return index == "1" ? "https://localhost:7041/img/Snipaste1.png" : "https://localhost:7041/img/Snipaste2.png";
        }
```